# MySQL копирование строки из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: phpmyadmin, синтаксис, sql, база-данных, mysql

```
INSERT INTO `blog_trash` (`id`, `tema`, `part`, `text`, `url`, `date`) 
select (`id`, `tema`, `part`, `text`, `url`, `date`) from blog 
WHERE `blog`.`id` =1
```

Выдает ошибку. Ругается на кавычки.... 
Имена таблиц правильные, ячейки существуют

> Executing query failed Incorrect table
> name '' Executing query failed A SQL
> error occured (1241): Operand should
> contain 1 column(s)

P.S. Знаю, что глупейший вопрос...

Comment: я б тоже ругнулся:

    `WHERE`

p.s. использовать backtick'и, конечно, хороший тон, но для однократно исполняемых запросов их можно и совсем не расставлять (в этом примере - только для date, и то наверняка mysql умеет с таким обращаться).

Comment: кавычки автодополняемые (не жалко), но вот вокруг WHERE  я уже почти всё перепробовал... и без них тоже ошибка...

Comment: @shilgen ну вот это тоже совсем не ок:

    `1`

MySQL воспримет это так: а принеси-ка мне значение колонки с названием 1.

Если и после этого проблема останется, то нужен будет текст ошибки для анализа (там, кстати, с вероятностью 90% и так все написано и объяснено).

Comment: вот без кавычек, всё равно ошибка, обновил в тексте вопроса

Comment: @shilgen, интернет говорит, что имена колонок после SELECT не должны оборачиваться в скобки, т.к. это меняет вывод команды. Почему указывается пустое table name - хз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скобки уберите из селекта. ругается не на кавычки, а на то, что у вас не указана таблица в выражении в скобках - mysql пытается проинтерпретировать выражение в скобках как вложенный запрос.

Comment: не работает
No rows affected. Query took 0.000601 seconds.
пробовал к к каждому элементу добавить : blog.
тоже не работает..

Comment: @shilgen, работает. у вас нет записей соответствующих фильтру `WHERE blog.id=1`.

Comment: спасибо Yura Ivanov, устал просто исправлять...